# How to skip OneNote 2016 "Cloud login"

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2016

I was using OneNote 2016 without any issues in my previous company laptop. I got a new laptop with windows 7 and office 2013 installed. I have installed OneNote 2016, however, when I click on OneNote icon, I am asked to log into cloud. When I click on "sign-in", I get a office-365 login scree. But, I only have hotmail account and I do not have office 365 account. I am totally stuck because I have stored all the onenote notes in Skydrive. Is there any way to skip this logon screen or is there a way to use skydrive instead of office-365?

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem using registering these keys. You need to save the below text as .reg file and apply it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OneNote\WebServiceProvider]
"DisableSkydriveSetupOnFirstBoot"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\Common\WebIntegration]
"WebIntegrationEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

[Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/24d8a941-1205-4ec2-83ad-4575961563b9/onenote-2016-suppress-first-run-prompt-to-sign-into-cloud?forum=Office2016setupdeploy)

Answer (score 4):

Add the following DWORD value in the registry before running OneNote:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OneNote]
"FirstBootStatus"=dword:01000101

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OneNote\Options]
"BootClippingPanelWithOneNote"=dword:00000000
```

*For OneNote 2013 change the 16.0 to 15.0

Reference: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5b6aef85-6f3b-4f16-943d-a39b0e577236/onenote-2013-disable-signin-screen-send-to-one-note-clipping-and-autoadd-to-startup?forum=officeitpro

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with OneNote 2016 (as part of the Office Home & Business Suite).  I finally relented and proceeded to sign in to MS.  Fortunately, I forgot my password.  The dialog skipped the rest of the sign in process and opened OneNote.